# o => o.MethodWithParameters  | is it possible to use a method in a lambda without () and parameters 

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

i have a method that takes as a parameter an expression because I need the method string name, and I don't care about the parameters of that method, is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is. You can however make a generic helper method that you can put in place of the parameters:

```
public T Any<T>(){
    return default(T);
}
```

and you can call it like so:

```
YourMethod((YourClass yc) => yc.SomeMethod(Any<SomeClass>(), Any<SomeOtherClass>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a concept proof test.

```
private static T RunExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T>> run )
        {
            var callExpression = (MethodCallExpression) run.Body;

            var procedureName = callExpression.Method.Name;

            Trace.WriteLine(procedureName);

            foreach (var argument in callExpression.Arguments)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(argument);
            }

            Trace.WriteLine(callExpression.Arguments.Count);

                    // Some really wicked stuff to assign out parameter
                    // Just for demonstration purposes

            var outMember = (MemberExpression)callExpression.Arguments[1];

            var e = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(outMember.Expression);
            var o = e.Compile().Invoke();

            var prop = o.GetType().GetField("s");
            prop.SetValue(o, "Hello from magic method call!");

            Trace.WriteLine(run.Body);
            return default(T);
        }



[TestMethod]
        public void TestExpressionInvocation()
        {
            var action = new MyActionObject();

            string s = null;
            RunExpression(() => action.Create(1, out s));

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello from magic method call!", s);
        }
```

Comment: I actually wanted something like this: var methodName = RunExpression<MyClass>(o => o.Method);

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this doesn't even use expression trees:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetNameOfMethod(new Action(Main)));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetNameOfMethod(new Func<Delegate, string>(GetNameOfMethod)));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetNameOfMethod(new Func<int, short, long>(AddNumber)));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetNameOfMethod(new Action<int, short>(SwallowNumber)));
}

string GetNameOfMethod(Delegate d){
    return d.Method.Name;
}

long AddNumber(int x, short y){ return x+y; }
void SwallowNumber(int x, short y){}
```

yields:

```
Main 
GetNameOfMethod 
AddNumber
SwallowNumber
```

I use this to build a BDD framework on http://storyq.codeplex.com.

[Click here to see the file where I do this.](http://storyq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/aa698f3f1637#src%2fStoryQ%2fFormatting%2fFormatter.cs)

Comment: If you are using method group, it could be even less verbose GetNameOfMethod(Main), but what about using method group outside the scope of the class?

Comment: GetNameOfMethod(Main) fails to compile because the type of Delegate isn't specified. As long as the method is accessible to the thing *calling* GetNameOfMethod this will work fine - you just have to pick an appropriate Delegate type...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method without parameters but parentheses (even empty) are required, because without them you tell the compiler to access a property of that name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:
(credits go to klausbyskov)
But it's less verbose.

Also you will need to provide overloads for various argument lists.

```
 [TestClass]
 public class TestExpressions
 {
  public class MyClass
  {
   public bool MyMethod(string arg)
   {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
  }

  private static string UseExpression<T, Ta1>(Expression<Action<T,Ta1>> run)
  {
   return ((MethodCallExpression)run.Body).Method.Name;
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestExpressionParser()
  {
   Assert.AreEqual("MyMethod",

   UseExpression<MyClass,string>((c,fakeString) => c.MyMethod(fakeString)));
  }
 }
```